# How do I have audio file not display URL or Page Title on Android notification bar?

Tags: html5-audio, dreamweaver

I have a site that has a list of audio files and I use the audio tag to display them on my site
Example:

```html
<audio controls style="width: 100%;">
 <source src="../audio/9am/message/9am.02.11.24_josh24.19-20.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
 <a href="../audio/9am/9am_12_11_22_josh15_42-47.mp3">
 <source src="../audio/9am/9am_12_18_22_josh15_48-60.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
 </a></audio>
```

And then below that I have a text link to play another audio file

Example

`<a href="../audio/9am/offertory/9am.02.11.24_offertory.mp3" title="Offertory">OFFERTORY</a>`

But when you click the audio tag one, it displays the page title name in the notification bar of an android and the text link displays the url.

[Audio Tag Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vi0x.jpg)

[URL Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M61A.jpg)

Is there a way to customize each one to display a title I assign it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API). It can for example be used to set the title of the currently playing media.

```js
navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({ title: 'My title' });
```